# implementing variable class types

Tags: c#, types

I have a list of objects which, depending on the condition that applies, has a variable type. However, I have not found a way to make this happen.

issue:
`cannot implicitly convert type List<TABLE_ONE> to type list<object>`

```
 List<object> listName;
    
    switch (sourceTableName)
    {
        case "TABLE_ONE":
            listName = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<TABLE_ONE>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}");
            break;
        case "TABLE_TWO":
            listName = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<TABLE_TWO>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}");
            break;
        case "TABLE_THREE":
            listName = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<TABLE_THREE>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}");
            break;
    }

foreach (var row in listName)
     {
        var dif3 = new DataInterfaceFactory(DatabaseTypes.SqlServer, row.DatabaseName, row.ServerName);
        do stuff...
     }
```

the variable `sourceTableName` is a string that contains the name of a class.

**Classes that are used as types:**

```
    public class TABLE_ONE
    {
        public int TableOneColumnUid;
        public string ServerName;
        public string DatabaseName;
        public DateTime LastCheckDate;
        public int IsRunning;
    }
    public class TABLE_TWO
    {
        public int TableTwoColumnUid;
        public string ServerName;
        public string DatabaseName;
        public DateTime LastCheckDate;
        public int IsRunning;
    }
    public class TABLE_THREE
    {
        public int TableThreeColumnUid;
        public string ServerName;
        public string DatabaseName;
        public DateTime LastCheckDate;
        public int IsRunning;
    }
```

Comment: Do the types `CALCULATION_SCHEDULE`, `UKPMS_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE` and `RCI_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE` have the same base type or share any interfaces?

Comment: also how do you what to further process `calcSched` after is has been assigned?

Comment: `List<T>` as with all classes in .NET, is not covariant. You may be able to use `IEnumerable<out T>` depending on your requirements. Also you should avoid `object`; if possible you should define a common base class or interface that exposes the required behaviour.

Comment: @Ackdari they represent different classes. they do not share any interfaces. It will further be processed with: `foreach (var row in calcSched) {...}`

Comment: If they do not share any common interface, what do you expect to do with them? `row` would be of type `object`, so all properties / methods defined on your classes will not be accessible. It seems like each type should be processed independently rather than trying to unify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) class implements [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netcore-3.1), you can use the `System.Linq` extension method [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult>(IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1) to cast a `List<T>` into a `List<Object>`.

To do so you would first want to ensure you have the `using` directive for `System.Linq` at the top of your file, then you would do something along the lines of the following:

```
List<ICALC_SCHED> calcSched; //note the interface being used here.

switch (sourceTableName)
{
    case "CALCULATION_SCHEDULE":
        calcSched = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<CALCULATION_SCHEDULE>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}").Cast<ICALC_SCHED>().ToList();
        break;
    case "UKPMS_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE":
        calcSched = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<UKPMS_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}").Cast<ICALC_SCHED>().ToList();
        break;
    case "RCI_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE":
        calcSched = m_api.Database.ExecuteQuery<RCI_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE>($"SELECT * FROM {sourceTableName}").Cast<ICALC_SCHED>().ToList();
        break;
    default:
        calcSched = null; //at this point you might want to leave your method early depending on context.
        //probably display some form of error message, note the "return" rather than "break" at the end of this case, this will leave the method early.
        return;
}
```

EDIT:
One way that you can access the common members of a set of classes is by having them inherit those members from an [`Interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/), and then treat the results all as instances of that interface. You could easily cast them back to the individual classes too, since the other data isn't lost - just the reference to the object is typed differently.

```
public interface ICALC_SCHED
{
    string ServerName;
    string DatabaseName;
    DateTime LastCheckDate;
    int IsRunning;
}

public class CALCULATION_SCHEDULE : ICALC_SCHED
{
    public int CalculationScheduleUid;
    public string ServerName;
    public string DatabaseName;
    public DateTime LastCheckDate;
    public int IsRunning;
}

public class UKPMS_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE : ICALC_SCHED
{
    public int UkpmsCalculationScheduleUid;
    public string ServerName;
    public string DatabaseName;
    public DateTime LastCheckDate;
    public int IsRunning;
}

public class RCI_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE : ICALC_SCHED
{
    public int RciCalculationScheduleUid;
    public string ServerName;
    public string DatabaseName;
    public DateTime LastCheckDate;
    public int IsRunning;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did fix that particular issue, however it has created an other error further down when trying to process calcSched. In the foreach statement calcSched is underlined with the message `use of unassigned local variable "calcSched"` (code above updated)

Comment: Change to `List<object> calcSched = null`

Comment: Added a default case in the switch statement.. what do you want the program to do if none of the specified cases are met?

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I tried that but it just shifted the error to `row.DatabaseName` and `row.ServerName`: "'object' does not contain a definition for 'DatabaseName/ServerName'"

Comment: if none of the specified cases are met it should error with a message to the user as the software would not be working as intended

Comment: are `UKPMS_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE` and `RCI_CALCULATION_SCHEDULE` subclasses of `CALCULATION_SCHEDULE`? If so then you can use `List<CALCULATION_SCHEDULE>` instead of `List<object>`.

Comment: No, they are all different classes

Comment: @NickyLarson I've updated the answer to explain one way of doing this, also probably worth looking into inheritance/polymorphism to learn about how a base class and subclasses would solve it.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and all makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

It would work, if you added a `.ToList<Object>();` at the end of your three calls.

I'm not sure whether that will actually solve your logic problem or just move it further down, but it would solve your immediate syntactical problem.